# need to add a close button to a fragment or to close an pop up activity just to go back to the previous screen

Tags: java, android

Hi I have a requirement that i need to add a close button to a pop menu or fragment , i know that i can just touch anywhere besides the pop menu to close or go back to the previous activity ,my question is there a code to close the fragment activity by adding a  button to it

what should be my approach should i add a close button and add intent to move it to the previous activity or is there a code to the close the activity

printf("%d\n", 42);  /* what was the
     question again? */

Answer (score 0):

under onclick method of your button add code like this

FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

transaction.replace(R.id.yourConatinerName, new yourFragment());
transaction.commint();

this will replace your current fragment with any fragment your want so the current fragmet disappears from view